# launching php script as root from command line

Tags: sudo, php-cli

How can I execute php script as root user?
I tried:
`sudo ./script.php`

and in my script I've got at 1 line: `#!/usr/bin/php`

Comment: So, what **happens** when you run it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you shouldn't need `#!/usr/bin/php` in your PHP script.
Presuming you've got `php` installed with the command available, try the below from command line:

```
sudo php path/to/script.php
```

...where `script.php` contains only PHP code.